# Leave specified folder intact when publishing to Azure Web app

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, lets-encrypt, azure-webapps

I'm using VS Code with the Azure App Service extension to publish to Azure. I have tested publishing to a staging slot and swapping slots with production. All is working well so far.

The trouble is that I have a script which uploads a new SSL certificate every 3 months (letsencrypt) to a folder called /.well-known. Each time I publish the site it's going to over-write this folder as the VS Code extension only seems capable of doing a complete publish of the whole site.

Is there a way of somehow "protecting" this folder so it never gets swapped out or over-riden?

I realise that if it wasn't for the automated nature of the SSL being uploaded I could just put the SSL in my repository and upload it each time. Or I could download this folder and include it in my project before each publish but this is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set the folder permissions so that when the deployment process attempts to delete the folder, it lacks permission? You can set such permissions by running the [attrib command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490868(v=technet.10)) in KUDU cmd.

Comment: Not sure, I would assume that the error would cause the deployment to fail. I will try though.